# How to check if Datatable value contains part of a string input?

Tags: c#

I want to check if a data table entry contains part of a user input string

E.g. In the data table if there is 123456, if the user enters 1234, I should get a match and get the values in that row.

Right now I can get the values in the row if there is an exact match,

My code for checking is:

```
string findPO = string.Format("PO = {0}",tbPOnum.Text);   

DataRow[] selectRow = localDataTable.Select(findPO);

localDataTable.Rows.IndexOf(selectRow[0]);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: are you familiar with using `DataView Filter Property` you can use this with a DataTable to do filtering using `LIKE` key word for example

Comment: @MethodMan No I'm quite new to data tables.

Comment: Are there any links where I can learn how to use filtering statements?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with the LIKE expression

```
string findPO = string.Format("Convert (PO,System.String) LIKE '*{0}*'",tbPOnum.Text);   

DataRow[] selectRow = localDataTable.Select(findPO);
```

This should return all rows containing the value.

For more information about the expressions you can use with the Select method, see information on [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Both the * and % can be used interchangeably for wildcard characters in a LIKE comparison. If the string in a LIKE clause contains a * or %, those characters should be enclosed in brackets ([]). If a bracket is in the clause, each bracket character should be enclosed in brackets (for example [[] or []]). A wildcard is allowed at the start and end of a pattern, or at the end of a pattern, or at the start of a pattern.
>
> Wildcard characters are not allowed in the middle of a string. For example, 'te*xt' is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now I get an exception that says
"Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String"

Comment: @ghostwar88 ok datatype of column po is int32. So we have to cast it to string before comparison

Answer (score 1):

@Jehof - The answer you provided was right (using the LIKE filter statement)

The field I was trying to search for was an int field,
After some research I got the following code which worked:

```
string findPO = string.Format("convert(PO, 'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%'", tbPOnum.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop rows and then columns (other vice versa) and check for any values of cells, for which `.IndexOf(findPO) == 0`. That means that the value of the cell begins with the given string. You may use linq as well. If you need a code example, just share.